# Bash wait for copy to finish

Tags: bash, macos

I have the following rename code being run via the OSX cron app Launch Control.

```
#!bin/bash
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING -mindepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/bin/rename -v 's/([0-9]*)_LK/$1_standard/' \;
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING -mindepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/bin/rename -v 's/([0-9]*)_ALT([0-9]*)/$1_alternate$2/' \;
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/ASPERA/ASPERA_STAGING -mindepth 2 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/bin/rename -v 's/([0-9]*)_SWATCH/$1_swatch/' \;
```

It's designed to rename certain files whenever a folder of files is copied to a directory called ASPERA_STAGING. The renaming works, the problem is that as soon as a folder starts copying to ASPERA_STAGING the script renames files before they are done copying. It's causing the computer to get confused and re-copy files. I tried adding Sleep but it's a terrible solution - there could be anywhere from 5-300 files in a folder so the copy times vary dramatically.

Is there something more complex that I could do to force the script to wait until all files in a folder have been copied before attempting the rename?

Comment: Generally, I'd suggest a complete rewrite in terms of how it works. For instance, if you were on Linux, you could be notified by incron as soon as a file is closed at the end of the write process. I have a vague recollection to the effect launchd can do something similar (invoking your script with the name of a file that was closed each time that operation takes place) on MacOS, but it'd be appropriate for someone who knows the platform better to answer.

Comment: That said, on platforms with standard UNIX semantics, a rename won't generally impact other processes trying to write to the same file, unless it's being written with a temporary name and then renamed afterwards -- in which case you should just skip anything with a temporary name.